# org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Arity [3] of result does not match the number[2] of requested type

Tags: apache-flink

I have a simple test case to learn how to use Table API and case/when as follows:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment

import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
object TableTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val te = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)
    val ds = env.fromCollection(Seq(Person("a",20), Person("b",40), Person("c", 60)))
    te.registerDataSet("person", ds)

    te.toDataSet[Person](table).print()


    val table = te.sqlQuery(
      """
         select name,age,
             case
                when age <= 20 then 'A'
                when age <=40 then 'B'
                when age <= 60 then 'C'
                else 'D'
            end as age_level
            from person
      """.stripMargin(' '))
    te.toDataSet[Person](table).print()
  }
}
```

When I run it, I encounter the following exception, the `age_level` is an calculated column, I don't know why the error occurs

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Arity [3] of result [ArrayBuffer(String, Integer, String)] does not match the number[2] of requested type [com.flink.table.Person(name: String, age: Integer)].
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.generateRowConverterFunction(TableEnvironment.scala:1165)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.BatchTableEnvironment.getConversionMapper(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:339)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.BatchTableEnvironment.translate(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:504)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.BatchTableEnvironment.translate(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:476)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.scala.BatchTableEnvironment.toDataSet(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:141)
    at com.flink.table.TableTest$.main(TableTest.scala:37)
    at com.flink.table.TableTest.main(TableTest.scala)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the table that you want to convert into a `DataSet[Person]` has **three** attributes: `(name, age, age_level)` while the `Person` case class only has **two** fields: `(name, age)`.

You could implement a new case class

```
case class PersonWithAgeLevel(name: String, age: Int, age_level: String)
```

and convert the table into a `DataSet[PersonWithAgeLevel]`.

Comment: Thanks @fabian-hueske, I understand now.